# webkit supporting html5 video tag on a target device

Tags: html, video, webkit, tags

I'm developing a mobile device running Qt on a kind of linux os and need to get html5 tags activated. Its webbrowser is isis-browser which is based on a webkit derived from Qt Webkit so I believe it should support a certain amount of html5 features especially video and audio as Qt webkit does.

But when I see sites like html5test.com and videojs.com on this webbrower, the video tag isn't working currently.

I'm not good at this embedded layer so it's not easy to figure out how to make it work with the tags..

1. on my small knowledge, this should have ffmpeg to decode video codecs but I can't find these code in the isis-browser packages or even in the qt webkit.
2. please guide me anything needed to be done..
3. https://github.com/isis-project

I appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks
Jun

Answer (score 0):

In *..\src\3rdparty\webkit\Source\WebCore\features.pri* writed:

```
linux-*:!contains(DEFINES, USE_QTMULTIMEDIA=1) {
        !contains(QT_CONFIG, no-pkg-config):system(pkg-config --exists glib-2.0 gio-2.0 gstreamer-0.10): {
            DEFINES -= ENABLE_VIDEO=0
            DEFINES += ENABLE_VIDEO=1
```

To me helped the install packets *glib-2.0, gio-2.0, gstreamer-0.10* and now my qtwebkit-based app support html5video.